# How to give more memory to IntelliJ Idea 9-11 

Tags: memory-management, intellij-idea, jvm-arguments

This concerns Intellij from 9 to 11.
In the IDEA window On the bottom right corner I see the current memory usage, typically "224M of 254M" How do I give more memory to Idea so it may read like "224M of 512M" ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On Mac, `$IDEA_HOME/Contents/Info.plist`

```
 ~: grep --context=5 Xmx /Applications/Maia-IU-94.426.app/Contents/Info.plist 
            <string>true</string>
            <key>apple.awt.fullscreencapturealldisplays</key>
            <string>false</string>
        </dict>
        <key>VMOptions</key>
        <string>-Xms128m -Xmx912m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -ea -agentlib:yjpagent=disablej2ee,disablecounts,disablealloc,sessionname=IntelliJIdea90 -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar</string>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>$APP_PACKAGE/bin</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

On Windows/Linux, `%IDEA_HOME%\bin\idea.vmoptions`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but on Windows, file name is `%IDEA_HOME%\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`

Comment: Note that on 10.8 Mountain Lion this does not work, you need to edit the $IDEA_APP/bin/idea.vmoptions instead.

Comment: agree with Erik, the answer doesn't apply for Lion, don't buy into votes

Comment: For me editing $IDEA_HOME/Contents/Info.plist on Mountain Lion worked

Comment: On OS X Mavericks, only idea.vmoptions worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

Edit the following file:

```
idea/bin/idea.vmoptions
```

Comment: Also see tsmets [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21001323/1251549) for x64 systems.

Answer (score 13):

For Windows, in your IntelliJ Idea folder modify `idea.exe.vmoptions`.

See http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/04/configuring-intellij-idea-vm-options/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am on MacOS. I don't see this file idea.exe.vmoptions
Specific number shouldn't matter but it is 10.5
Thanks

Comment: In IntelliJ Idea 10.5. For 64bit. version edit idea64.exe.vmoptions

Answer (score 7):

If you are using:

- Ubuntu
- 64 bit hardware

then you need to create *idea64.vmoptions* by simply copying the options from idea.vmoptions file

```
cat idea.vmoptions > idea64.vmoptions
```

The parameters remain the same: -Xmx1024M -Xms512M

Comment: Newer versions (12.1+) apparently include `idea64.vmoptions`. If unsure which one you need, check the output of `uname -i`.

Answer (score 5):

On the MacOS find the folder where Idea is installed. then open file

```
Contents/Info.plist
```

Go all the way to the bottom and find the section that looks like this:

```
<key>VMOptions</key> <string>-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xbootclasspath/p:
```

Answer (score 4):

go to that path "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions" and change size to -Xmx512m

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

hope its will work

Answer (score 2):

On windows 7 (64-bits).

In the folder : *C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.0\bin*

There is a file named : *idea64.exe.vmoptions*

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

Beware that if the underlying JVM used is 32-bits, the maximum memory is still somewhere below 2048Mb