# How to stop IntelliJ truncating output when I run a build?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run our build from IntelliJ it pumps out a lot of debugging.

But it gets truncated in the `Run` console.

***Can I make IntelliJ preserve more output?***
Or, preferably, all of it?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

By a popular request **Override console cycle buffer size** setting was added to the UI 9/14/16:

[image: Override console cycle buffer size]

---

Original answer for older versions:

Edit your `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties` file, and increase this setting:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# This option controls console cyclic buffer: keeps the console output size not higher than the specified buffer size (Kb). Older lines are deleted.
# In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled
idea.cycle.buffer.size=1024
```

then restart IntelliJ.

Comment: What's the default value of this?

Comment: @TimBüthe 1024KB (1MB).

Comment: What will happen if I will disable it?

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko the buffer will fill until OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: This would be a great setting for IDEA to put into the Config/Settings UI. Like Eclipse has it. Would that be too "intelligent"?

Comment: For me on mac this file was located at `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties`

Comment: For my distro (Arch), `idea.properties` is located at `/usr/share/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/bin/idea.properties`. Note that for Linux (unlike Mac) you don't need to create a copy of this file.

Comment: Go to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63980 to vote for this to become a true preference!

Comment: At least by version 14, there is a comment: "Older lines are deleted. In order to disable cycle buffer use idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled". This works perfectly.

Comment: On OSX I had to copy that file from /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties to ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/idea.properties
Otherwise it wouldn't react on the change

Comment: Settings > Editor > General > Console > "Override console cycle buffer size (1024kb) {enter a value}"

Comment: @ThomasW Seeing that IntelliJ have now added this to feature since your comment...

Comment: FYI I set my buffer size to about 1G and it causes IDEA to lag like crazy. Eventually it gave me a popup asking to increase the memory. So you'll want to do that. I set mine to 2G. 
On the Help menu, click Edit Custom VM Options. Set the -Xmx option to a higher value and restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @ThomasW - Would it be better if inteliij did not truncate logs by default ? My colleague saw some errors in a script logs, but I did not because my logs were getting truncated. A bit frustrating.

Comment: I set the console buffer size to 102400kb but still can only get part of the info in the console, is there a way that I can store all the running process in one file?

Answer (score 40):

This can (now) be edited in the Intellij IDEA settings.

[image: Intellij IDEA Settings: Console]

This has probably been in Intellij IDEA for a while, and certainly is as of Intellij IDEA 15.

Comment: Not in the latest Webstorm (and presumably not in other IntelliJ applications other than IntelliJ itself).  C'mon Jetbrains, why the hate for people using non-Java languages?

Answer (score 16):

The problem increasing the console cylce buffer size is that you are likely to run out of heap space, and then you will need to [bump up the max heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435569/how-to-give-more-memory-to-intellij-idea-9-11). For an app that generates a very large amount of output it probably won't help as you will not have enough physical memory.

I would suggest instead that you capture the [console output in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121721/configure-intellij-to-print-the-standard-output-in-the-console-window-but-also-s/8122275#8122275).

Comment: what is "this approach"?

Comment: Thank you, I had not idea this was an option within Intellij. Great little feature to know about.

Answer (score 5):

Accepted answer did not work for me (IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 Mac). What did work was increasing "Terminal scrollback buffer size" in Preferences/Advanced Settings.

[Screenshot of terminal scrollback buffer size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s73No.png).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: @MousamSingh How does this not answer the question?

Comment: @MousamSingh This does answer the question. This is the only answer that worked for me in Rider to get more lines in the Run output window.

Answer (score 3):

With IntelliJ 11 (on the Mac at least), this setting is configured instead in Info.plist:

```
IDEA_HOME/Contents/Info.plist
```

There should already be a value there so just modify it instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Be careful with IDEA 12 and later, it should be modified in a copy of `idea.properties` file, [more details here](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this shortcut

```
Ctrl + Shift + A
```

then search "Override console cycle buffer size"
to get to the settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using saved configurations to start your app, make sure this option is disabled: "Emulate terminal in output console". With this option enabled, the output would be always cut after a few hundred lines. Without it, I think the option described in the other answers is respected.

[image]