# IntelliJ still truncates output

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836313/how-to-stop-intellij-truncating-output-when-i-run-a-build), did not help.

Running IntelliJ 13.1.4 on Windows 7.  I want to see the full output when I run my project; instead, I see only a truncated snippet:

[image: ... 9 more]

I copied idea.properties to C:\Users\.IdeaIC13 and changed idea.cycle.buffer.size to various values - disabled, 65535, etc.  No change, whenever I build, I still see truncated output.  How do I get my full build output?

Comment: Click it? The dots I mean. Or maybe the "Expand All" button at the left side? Ctrl + Numpad_+

Comment: Nothing to click (see img above).  It's just hidden output.

Comment: try Settings | Editor | Console Folding

Answer (score 2):

The text

```
... 9 more
```

is produced by the JVM, not intelliJ

What it is telling you is; the next 9 lines are the same as it's parent. As you have three nested stack traces, it doesn't show you the full stack trace three times, instead it only shows you the additional stack traces, for each nested exception/error.

Comment: Okay.  That's certainly not clear from the outset but, okay.  So, if I understand correctly, I should take the 9 lines from the first stack trace and replicate them to each successive one (where the "... 9 more" is printed, in order to get the proper picture?

Comment: @Jon You need to reverse the order of the three exceptions.

Comment: So, read it bottom up, but the "... 9 more" would be replicated top down.  Weird way of presenting data.  Is there a way to have the jvm not do that? I'd prefer to just have the big data dump.