# IntelliJ IDEA terminal unlimited scrollback

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently started using the terminal window inside of IntelliJ IDEA so that I don't context switch between IDE and the Mac terminal window.

On my Mac terminal, I had set "unlimited scrollback" to true which means that when I am running my unit tests, I can scroll through the entire run.

Now inside of IntelliJ terminal, when I run my tests, it truncates the output and therefore I cannot go to the beginning of the test run.

I tried looking in the settings, but I didn't find anything which will give me a unlimited scrollback.

Comment: Maybe this helps (searching for "buffer size"): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836313/how-to-stop-intellij-truncating-output-when-i-run-a-build

Answer (score 23):

you can increase the lines of the terminal if you desire:
In intellij goto the registry (press cntrl+shift+a and write registry, and click it). look for: terminal.buffer.max.lines.count
and increase it from the 1000 lines it has. (I entered 9999 and for my runs it did the job)

Comment: there is no registry on linux and macs

Comment: [Better late than never] The "registry" here is _not_ the Windows registry; instead this is an Intellij-specific configuration registry, much like Firefox's about:config "registry" page

Comment: it seems that key got removed - at least here in phpstorm 2019.3 I don't have this setting (it is sorted alphabetically, right?)

Comment: ah sorry - it is not sorted alphabetically: already changed values are on the top :smile:

Answer (score 10):

This setting was moved in UI starting 2021.2, you can find it at Settings | Advanced Settings: Terminal > Terminal scrollback buffer size

[image]

Source Link for the answer: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206381169/comments/4405562193298

Comment: This setting is in pycharm too and easily located via the search for `scrollback`.