# How to remove ... when print out and print out the full sentences in the console of Pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pycharm

The below shown is the output console in pycharm. I would like to show a long sentence print out but it gives me ...

```
                                             notes
0  {'Notes': "85 Male Malay  NKDA walking stick a...
1  {'Notes': '85yo chinese man nkda PHX 1) Hypert...
```

This is the codes I used to achieved the print out:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 100000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000, 'display.max_columns', 500)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(c3), columns=["notes"]).drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop IntelliJ truncating output when I run a build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836313/how-to-stop-intellij-truncating-output-when-i-run-a-build)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC using `pd.options`

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 1000
pd.Series('this is very long long long long long long long long long string')
Out[39]: 
0    this is very long long long long long long long long long string
dtype: object
```

Update

```
pd.Series([{'LOL!':'this is very long long long long long long long long long stridddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddng','LOL2':'this is very long long long long long long long long long string'}])
Out[47]: 
0    {'LOL2': 'this is very long long long long long long long long long string', 'LOL!': 'this is very long long long long long long long long long stridddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddng'}
dtype: object
```

Comment: It does work, but why is the data not aligned... @Wen

Comment: @Lynn I think that may because of the dict

Comment: @Lynn seems like working on my side , would you like make your dataframe head, using df.head().to_dict() and post the result here ?

Comment: Still the same output :O @Wen

Comment: I got only one column. However I added the c3 which is an array into numpy array. Purpose of doing so is to conduct text analysis later @Wen