# How can I store the spark's log output when launching in my local machine through intellij?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, intellij-idea

I'm developing a software based on scala-spark and I need to test it at my local machine first. Whenever I launch my class I get an output through Intellij IDEA and I would like to store it, since Intellij can't show the complete log, it shows only "a few" lines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark uses log4j for its logging. The default configuration logs to console. You need to pass it a different `log4j.properties` file, either by changing the existing file in the conf folder, or by passing it a different file via the option `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties`.

You can also [increase IntelliJ's console output buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836313/how-to-stop-intellij-truncating-output-when-i-run-a-build) so it doesn't truncate.