# Remove 49 character limit when printing in PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I've been trying to retrieve the entire output after printing a statement however PyCharm is stopping the full output from printing if it is longer than 49 characters. Here is an example :

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdpOv.png)

I have tried every solution I could find but there is nothing that allows me to expand this limit. Here are some solutions I tried.

```
desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Is there any method for the full output?

Comment: I edited the question to increase the size of the image(`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR1f8.png" height="75">`), feel free to rollback if not ok.

Comment: I think the title of question is wrong. If I interpret the question correctly: "How to remove 49 character limit when printing international string in Pandas". (possibly with real language, or something better instead of "international")

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the below link. It may resolve your issue. In Pycharm setting also this options is available.

[How to stop IntelliJ truncating output when I run a build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836313/how-to-stop-intellij-truncating-output-when-i-run-a-build)

Comment: But this is about coding style in the editor (and just for warnings). It has nothing to do with terminal